# No puedo imprimir reporte .CSV, solo aparece código de consulta a base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, csv

Intento generar un reporte descargable, cuando le de en botón con **name="generar_reporte"** me genere la descarga. Lo único que realiza es imprimir mi consulta:

```
query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Gang ='$grupo'"); while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['username'], $filaR['Date'], $filaR['IDGame'], $filaR['Client'], $filaR['Gang'], $filaR['Intento']));
} ?>
```

Este es mi código:

```
<?
include('conexion.php');//CONEXION A LA BD

$grupo=$_POST['grupo'];


if(isset($_POST['generar_reporte']))
{
    // NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO Y CHARSET
    header('Content-Type:text/csv; charset=latin1');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reporte.csv"');

    // SALIDA DEL ARCHIVO
    $salida=fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // ENCABEZADOS
    fputcsv($salida, array('username', 'Date', 'IDGame', 'Client', 'Gang', 'Intento'));
    // QUERY PARA CREAR EL REPORTE
    $reporteCsv=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Gang ='$grupo'");
    while($filaR= $reporteCsv->fetch_assoc())
        fputcsv($salida, array($filaR['username'], 
                                $filaR['Date'],
                                $filaR['IDGame'],
                                $filaR['Client'],
                                $filaR['Gang'],
                                $filaR['Intento']));

}

?>
```

Comment: Revisa que en tu servidor puedes tienes activa la directiva [short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) o, simplemente cambia `<?` por `<?php`

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la query retorna filas? Chequea que ingrese al bucle (while). ¿Las cabeceras tampoco aparecen en el archivo .csv?